# Error de ingreso de datos a la Base de datos de Acces, con Visual Basic

Tags: base-de-datos, visual-studio, vb.net, formularios, ms-access

Estoy haciendo un login con base de datos, en el que el login main es el Form1, este pide datos del usuario los cuales son su nombre de usuario y su contraseña.
Cada usuario tiene ademas un rol, ya sea "invitado" o "admin", si el usaurio que ingresa al login es invitado lo mandara a otro form llamada "FormInvitado", pero si es admin, lo enviara al "FormAdministrador", donde podria agregar, eliminar y actualizar nuevos usuarios.

La base de datos parrece funcionar ya que si reconoce a los usuarios y los manda a sus respectivos formularios, el problema es que en el de admin, al intentar ingresar un nuevo usuario este da un error.

Coloco el codigo del formAdmin, del form principal, del modulo que uso, tambien la imagen del error y la imagen de la tabla de la base de datos.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

[image: Base de Datos]
[image: Error]
**Modulo:**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Funciones

    Public conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Login.accdb")
    Public camd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Public sql As String = ""
    Public miDataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader 'datosnuevos

    Public Sub conectarse()
        Try
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("Conexión iniciada")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub desconectarse()
        MsgBox("Cerrando conexion")
        conn.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Function ValidarCredenciales(usuario As String, contraseña As String) As String
        Dim rol As String = "" ' Variable para almacenar el rol del usuario

        ' Query SQL para verificar las credenciales en la tabla "Usuarios" de tu base de datos de Access
        Dim query As String = "SELECT rol FROM usuarios WHERE user = @Usuario AND userPassword = @Contraseña"

        ' Abre la conexión a la base de datos de Access si no está abierta
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contraseña", contraseña)

            ' Ejecuta la consulta SQL en la base de datos de Access
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.Read() Then
                ' Si las credenciales son válidas, obtén el rol del usuario
                rol = reader("rol").ToString()
            End If
        End Using

        ' Cierra la conexión a la base de datos de Access si está abierta
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If

        Return rol ' Devuelve el rol del usuario (puede ser "Invitado", "Administrador" u otro valor)
    End Function
End Module`
```

**Form Admin:**

```
Public Class FormAdministrador
    Dim id As Integer = 0
    Dim usuario As String = ""
    Dim contraseña As String = ""
    Dim rol As String = ""

    Private Sub btnRegresar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegresar1.Click
        Me.Close()
        Form1.Show()

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click
        If txtId1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("El campo de id no puede estar vacio", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Atencion")
            Me.txtId1.Select()
        Else

            id = Val(txtId1.Text)
            usuario = txtUser1.Text
            contraseña = txtPass1.Text
            rol = txtRol1.Text

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = conn

            sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id, user, userPassword, rol) "
            sql += "VALUES (" & id & ", '" & usuario & "','" & contraseña & "', '" & rol & "')"
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            Try
                conn.Open() ' Abre la conexión a la base de datos
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("INFORMACIÓN GUARDADA")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                'Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
            Finally
                If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    conn.Close() ' Asegúrate de cerrar la conexión después de usarla
                End If
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Form Principal (del login):**

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim usuario As String = ""
    Dim contraseña As String = ""

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conectarse()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        desconectarse()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnSalir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSalir.Click
        Application.Exit()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLimpiar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLimpiar.Click
        txtContraLogin.Clear()
        txtUsuarioLogin.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnIngresar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnIngresar.Click
        ' Obtén el nombre de usuario y la contraseña ingresados por el usuario
        usuario = txtUsuarioLogin.Text
        contraseña = txtContraLogin.Text

        ' Realiza la validación de las credenciales (esto puede variar según tu base de datos y lógica de autenticación)    
        Dim rol As String = ValidarCredenciales(usuario, contraseña)

        ' Verifica el rol del usuario
        If rol = "invitado" Then
            ' Si el usuario es invitado, muestra el formulario correspondiente
            Dim formularioInvitado As New FormInvitado()
            Me.Hide()
            formularioInvitado.Show()
            txtContraLogin.Clear()
            txtUsuarioLogin.Clear()

        ElseIf rol = "admin" Then
            ' Si el usuario es administrador, muestra el formulario correspondiente
            Dim formularioAdministrador As New FormAdministrador()
            Me.Hide()
            formularioAdministrador.Show()
            txtContraLogin.Clear()
            txtUsuarioLogin.Clear()

        Else
            ' Las credenciales son incorrectas
            MsgBox("Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error de inicio de sesión")
            txtUsuarioLogin.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor imprimi el insert, lo que esta dentro de la variable sql tu error es esa instruccion

Comment: que parte queres que te imprima?, no te comprendi bien.

Comment: si te da error el insert, tenemos que ver como se arma el insert... mostra el insert...

Comment: pero el insert esta ahi, en el "Form Admin", y aunque dice eso, tambien me marca que el error se produce en la linea 31, que es:
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
que esta dentro del try catch

Comment: no.. no entendes.. tenemos que ver el contenido, como queda construido... que variables recibe, cual es el insert real que se ejecuta... porque vos construis un string con valores que recibis de un form... como queda construido ese string?